# Container is unable to be contacted by outside systems

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The piece of software that I am trying to containerize has multiple ports open from 41001. When trying to connect using a host-machine based application to the IP that the container is set to, I am unable to measure any traffic coming across the port while using WSL. There is a piece of this application that sends across information every couple of seconds on port 41001, that can be used to see if the bytes are being sent.

Using telnet, measuring `telnet 127.0.0.1 41001` while in the container measures the binary data that the software is sending. However, while on the host-machine's WSL, the data does not come through.

I have tried disabling my Windows 10 firewall, but that does not seem to make a difference here. Is there any additional layer of firewall or protection that I need to allow my container to bypass?

Below you can see my Dockerfile and docker-compose, both of which I believe are set up correctly for this application to pass through.

Dockerfile

```
# Use Ubuntu 18.04 as Base Image
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

FROM base
WORKDIR /home/user/
COPY application .
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/
RUN chmod +x application

# What the container should run when it is started.
CMD [ "/home/user/application"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  application:
    build: .
    working_dir: /home/user/
    tty: true
    command: /home/user/application
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9998-9999:9998-9999/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:21901:21901"
      - "127.0.0.1:41001:41001"
      - "127.0.0.1:41003:41003"
      - "127.0.0.1:41007:41007"
      - "127.0.0.1:41028:41028"
```